# Search box to work on both click a button PHP Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i am trying to get a search box to work on both click a button or an enter action yet i cant get the enter action to work as well as enter.
I know this isnt strictly php but i am using all php functions with the search and wondered if anyone could help.

This is my code:

```
function get() {
    $.post('search_tsr.php', {
        search_term: form.name.value
    }, function (output) {
        $('#search_results').html(output).show();
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#form").submit();
            $.post('search_tsr.php', {
                search_term: form.name.value
            }, function (output) {
                $('#search_results').html(output).show();
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Form :

```
<form name="form">
    <img src="gfx/search_magnifyer.jpg" width="18" height="18" border="0"
    align="absmiddle">
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <input type="button" onClick="get()" value="Go">
</form>
```

Anyone can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get either "Enter button" or "Button click" to work, change the type of your button to "submit" instead of button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Go">
```

Then you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#searchform").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // prevents default form submition
      get(); // executes your get function
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `onClick` event, use the `submit` event.

Give your form an id of `searchform` and do

```
$('#searchform').submit(function(){
  // do your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make input type submit and call your function onsubmit event of form. you can do

in this way 
return false in `get()` if you want to use ajax.

```
 <form name="form" onsubmit="return get();">
              <img src="gfx/search_magnifyer.jpg" width="18" height="18" border="0" align="absmiddle">   
              <input name="name" type="text"><input type="submit" value="Go">
```

Comment: You don't need to check for enter key in javascript browser will submit form on enter key itself.